# Does ReadFile() always return FALSE if completing asynchronously?

Tags: winapi

Does ReadFile() always return FALSE if completing asynchronously ? Or is there an exception, f.e. when the read-request is immediately completed via copying from the filesystem-cache ? I'm asking not about the special case when the number of bytes to transfer is zero.

Comment: what you mean under I/O *completing asynchronously* ?

Answer (score 2):

Even when invoked asynchronously ReadFile has the possibility of completing synchronously. If ReadFile returns true then it completed synchronously regardless of the handle having been opened for overlapped IO. A return of FALSE from ReadFile but a result other than ERROR_IO_PENDING from GetLastError() indicates that there was actually a problem with the call to ReadFile. The only case where ReadFile actually completes asynchronously is where it returns FALSE and GetLastError() returns ERROR_IO_PENDING.

Comment: Can you show me a link where the documentation says that an overlapped operation may end synchronously ? What you say rather seems an interpretation.

Comment: Take a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sync/synchronization-and-overlapped-input-and-output keyed on the text "the operation might be completed before the function returns"